# JPEG images display on iOS

Tags: ios, uikit, core-animation, opengl-es-2.0

I am receiving series of jpeg encoded NSData from a server that contains small images (~400x400) at a high frame rate (30 fps or more). Since jpeg decoding be anyways done by iOS, is there any advantage of using OpenGLES for displaying the images or Core Animation (or even UIKit) should be sufficient in such cases?

Comment: Can I know what you meant by "I am receiving series of jpeg encoded NSData from a server that contains small images (~400x400) at a high frame rate (30 fps or more)" so that I can answer it? Does it mean 30+ images(400px*400px) per second?  It must not be like that.. right?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use Image I/O （like CGImageSourceCreateWithData）or GPUImage

Comment: GPUImage still uses OpenGLES, my point is there an advantage of using OpenGLES to display data that is in CPU memory?

Answer (score 0):

Core Animation's optimisations and handling of image work is done on the GPU with Metal, in most modern iOS devices.

And the best choice for this.